# Grails create-drop in a cluster Tomcat

Tags: mysql, tomcat, grails

Can we use "create-drop" in a cluster tomcat? Or we can only use "validate"?

I can deploy my app to one tomcat Dev server. There is no issue.

But it doesn't work when i deploy war file into a cluster Tomcat that shares one MySql server. I see that tables are not created correctly and some data are corrupted.

Is "create-drop" the issue? If yes. How can i have a "create-drop" in a cluster env?

- dbCreate: create-drop
- Grails 3.1
- Java 8
- Tomcat 7, three instances
- MySql, one instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are running multiple copies of the same Grails application in a cluster you need to manage the database migrations and data structure outside of the built in `create`, `create-drop`, or `update`.

Think about it logically, which application is going to be responsible for it when all of them are trying to do the same thing? They will step on one another's toes.

Fortunately, you can use the [Database Migration Plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/) for Grails instead.